# How to enable fastboot in u-boot for am335x-evm-sk in PROCESSOR-SDK-LINUX-AM335X-EVM

Tags: linux, embedded, u-boot

I need a step by step procedure for enabling fastboot in am335x-evm-sk in Linux (not Android!).

- Firstly, how can I enumerate the `u-boot` as a usb device?
- Then, how can I make it a `fastboot` device?
- The OS flavor is embedded linux.
- The board is http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdssk3358.
- Technical Reference Manual: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73q/spruh73q.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to make it easier for contributors to help you, please provide some more details on the OS flavor and version. Also, since not everyone will be familiar with it, please add a link to more information on that embedded board you are searching a solution for.

Comment: The OS flavor would be embedded linux. The link for the Technical Reference Manual: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73q/spruh73q.pdf